# Change the position of the block created from the Locale module

Tags: 7, theming

I am using Drupal 7, and I have enabled the Locale module. I have configured the block so  that it appears on the header, but I want the block to appear near the site's name.

How can I do it? Which files need to be changed?

I am using a Zen sub-theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your block into any region you like on the general block config page.

If this is not enough you can change everything about a region in the page.tpl.php file or the corresponding CSS files.